# Save Records to DataBase using C# sql in windows form datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I'm having trouble when I save my records to DataBase using C# sql windows form Datagrid,I lose all my Records when I restart my application or when I catch an exception error but this problem does not happen often but when there is exception error all my records are lost

Here is my Save button code.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                //Reconnect to Database
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
                cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                // cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables["Impi"]);

                //Create a new row
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables["tblImpi"].NewRow();


                //save the record to first column
                dr[0] = txtSerial.Text;

                //Check data entry if its no empt
                if (txtName.Text != "")
                {

                    dr[1] = txtName.Text;

                }

                //Check if combox has values and assign one the values to it
                if (cbModel.Text == "MKI" || cbModel.Text == "MKII")
                {
                    dr[2] = cbModel.Text;
                }

                if (cbStatus.Text == "Serviceble" || cbStatus.Text == "Unserviceble")
                {
                    dr[3] = cbStatus.Text;
                }

                if (cbDeprtmnt.Text == "AIR" || cbDeprtmnt.Text == "LAND" || cbDeprtmnt.Text == "NAVY" || cbDeprtmnt.Text == "SPECIAL FORCE")
                {


                    dr[4] = cbDeprtmnt.Text;
                }

                if (cmbVesrion.Text == "10" || cmbVesrion.Text == "11" || cmbVesrion.Text == "12")
                {
                    dr[5] = cmbVesrion.Text;
                }



                if (txtGsm.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    dr[6] = txtGsm.Text;
                }

                if (txtImei.Text.Length != 0)
                {
                    dr[7] = txtImei.Text;
                }
                //Check if serial number value is not zero
                if ((txtSerial.Text.Length != 0) || (txtGsm.Text.Length!=0) || (txtImei.Text.Length!=0))
                {
                    //Create a search Method to search before you save the serial number
                    bool search = SearchRecBeforeSave(txtSerial.Text, txtName.Text,txtGsm.Text,txtImei.Text);
                    //bool search = SearchSerialNumberBeforeSave(txtSerial.Text);
                    if (search == false)
                    {
                        // DialogResult dr2 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure  you want to save this serial number", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        if (txtGsm.Text == "")
                        {
                           txtGsm.Text = "";
                            txtGsm.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtGsm, txtGsm.Text);

                        }

                        if (txtImei.Text == "")
                        {
                            txtImei.Text = " ";
                            txtImei.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtImei, txtImei.Text);

                        }

                        if (txtName.Text.Length == 0)
                        {

                            txtName.Text = "";
                            txtName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtName, txtName.Text);
                        }

                        else if (txtGsm.Text != "" && txtImei.Text != "" && txtName.Text.Length != 0)
                        {


                            DialogResult dr2 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure  you want to save this serial number", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                            if (dr2 == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                ds.Tables["tblImpi"].Rows.Add(dr);
                                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb1;
                                cb1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                                cb1.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables["tblImpi"]);
                                // dataAdapter.Update(ds,"Impi");
                               // maxRow = maxRow + 1;
                              //  inc = maxRow - 1;


                                MessageBox.Show("Serial Number Added Successful");
                            }


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Fix this part
                            MessageBox.Show("This Serial Number Exist and will create the duplicate.\nSerial Number not Saved");
                            MessageBox.Show("Data Entry was not saved", "Sorry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The information that you have enterd already exist\nPlease Enter a Correct Entries ", "Data Entry");
                        txtSerial.Text = "Please Enter Impi Serial Number";
                        txtSerial.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtSerial, txtSerial.Text);

                        txtName.Text = "Please Enter the Track Number";
                            txtName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtName, txtName.Text);


                        txtGsm.Text = "Please Enter the GSM Sim Number";
                            txtGsm.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtGsm, txtGsm.Text);

                        txtImei.Text = "Please Enter the IMEI Number ";
                            txtImei.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtImei, txtImei.Text);
                        }
                    }


                }


            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                //MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Data Entry", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            con.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for the question I haves asked I managed to solved it

```
#region Save the Records to the DataBase

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                //Reconnect to Database
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
                cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

                //Create a new row
                DataRow dr = ds.Tables["tblImpi"].NewRow();

                //save the record to first column
                dr[0] = txtSerial.Text;

                //Check data entry if its not empty
                if (txtcallSign.Text != "")
                {

                    dr[1] = txtcallSign.Text;

                }

                //Check if ip textbox is empty
                if (txtIp.Text != "")
                {
                    dr[2] = txtIp.Text;
                }

                //Check if port is empty
                if (txtPort.Text != "")
                {
                    dr[3] = txtPort.Text;
                }

                //check if gsm txtbox is empty
                if (txtGsm.Text != "")
                {


                    dr[4] = txtGsm.Text;
                }

                //check iriduim txtbox
                if (txtiriduim.Text != "")
                {
                    dr[5] = txtiriduim.Text;
                }


                //check software version
                if (txtSoftVersion.Text != "")
                {
                    dr[6] = txtSoftVersion.Text;
                }


                //Check if serial number,gsm sim,iriduim value is not zero
                if ((txtSerial.Text.Length != 0) || (txtGsm.Text.Length != 0) || (txtiriduim.Text.Length != 0))
                {
                    //Create a search Method to search before you save the serial number
                    bool search = SearchRecBeforeSave(txtSerial.Text, txtGsm.Text, txtiriduim.Text);
                    //bool search = SearchSerialNumberBeforeSave(txtSerial.Text);
                    if (search == false)
                    {

                        DialogResult dr2 = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to  save", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        if (dr2 == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            ds.Tables["tblImpi"].Rows.Add(dr);
                            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb1;
                            cb1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                            cb1.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables["tblImpi"]);



                            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved","Save");
                        }



                        // DialogResult dr2 = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure  you want to save this serial number", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        else if (txtGsm.Text == "")
                        {
                            txtGsm.Text = "";
                            txtGsm.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtGsm, txtGsm.Text);

                        }

                        else if (txtiriduim.Text == "")
                        {
                            txtiriduim.Text = " ";
                            txtiriduim.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtiriduim, txtiriduim.Text);

                        }

                        else if (txtcallSign.Text.Length == 0)
                        {

                            txtcallSign.Text = "";
                            txtcallSign.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            tootip.SetToolTip(txtcallSign, txtcallSign.Text);
                        }


                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The information that you have enterd already exist\nPlease Enter a Correct Entries ", "Data Entry");
                        txtSerial.Text = "Please Enter Impi Serial Number";
                        txtSerial.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtSerial, txtSerial.Text);

                        txtcallSign.Text = "Please Enter Call Sign";
                        txtcallSign.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtcallSign, txtcallSign.Text);


                        txtIp.Text = "Please Enter Ip Adress";
                        txtIp.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtIp, txtIp.Text);

                        txtPort.Text = "Please Enter Port Number";
                        txtPort.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtPort, txtPort.Text);

                        txtGsm.Text = "Please Enter the GSM Sim Number";
                        txtGsm.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtGsm, txtGsm.Text);

                        txtiriduim.Text = "Please Enter the IMEI Number ";
                        txtiriduim.ForeColor = Color.Red;

                        tootip.SetToolTip(txtiriduim, txtiriduim.Text);
                    }
                }

                else if ((txtSerial.Text == "") && (txtIp.Text == "") && (txtPort.Text == "") && (txtiriduim.Text == "") && txtGsm.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a data", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

            }


            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                //MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Data Entry", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            con.Close();

        }
```